# Angular bind with property name using string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Is it possible to bind (one-way and two way) an angular object but using a dynamic string.

So instead of doing

```
{{ myObject.name }}
```

I can do this, which works fine

```
{{ myObject['name'] }}
```

But what about if the property name is in another variable in scope?  This doesnt work

```
{{ myObject['{{ anotherVar }}'] }}
```

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`{{}}` is meant to interpolate into html text.  You are "already there".  Try this:

```
{{ myObject[anotherVar] }}
```

I didn't test it.  It's valid javascript, but I have no idea if it is valid "angular-script"